# HttpClient PostAsyc response.Content gets cut off after 20KB

Tags: c#, xamarin

I communicate with a JSON backend to fetch data. I send and recieve the Data with this code:

```
Uri targetUri = new Uri(url);
HttpContent httpData = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
HttpResponseMessage resp = await httpClient.PostAsync(targetUri, httpData).ConfigureAwait(false);
string data = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The server sends the full data but the result string in the frontend is cut off after it reaches 20KB in size.

EDIT: By cut off i mean the string data does not include the complete everything sent by the server. The string content just stops after it reaches 20KB in size. The shown code doesnt produce any error messages.

Comment: It's not clear at what point the "cutting-off" is occurring. Is `data` cut off? Or is the problem somewhere else?

Comment: Have tried running this in debug? If  you put a break point below the row `ReadAsStringAsync(),` does the data variable contain the whole value sent from the server? If so it would seem to be a problem in the display, not with the request

Comment: I checked it in debug. It is cut off there too. I used the data from there to determine the 20KB as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't get it. You're saying the content of the `data` variable is missing something? There is nothing here that will cut data off, it's the server that isn't sending it.

Comment: I am running the server on a local machine and installed wireshark on it. I checked the outgoing data and everything seems to be there.

Comment: Did you try to get the data from another way to see if it is the same behavior? I mean something like a postman and etc..